# Any idea why initWithFormat causes a crash when its arguments contains a %

Tags: ios, objective-c

The following function has worked fine for a long time till today. Today I added the arm64 architecture flag to the app's Build Settings and added -ObjC to the app's Other Linker Flags (in Build Settings) and now a seemingly innocent call to `initWithFormat:` crashes the app!

The function is this:

```
void CRLog(NSString* temp, ...)
{
    va_list arg_list;
    va_start(arg_list, temp);

    NSLogv(temp, arg_list); 
    //The line that causes the crash
    NSString* str = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:temp arguments:arg_list] autorelease];

    // do something here with str
    ...

    va_end(arg_list);
}
```

Specifically the call to CRLog that causes the app to crash is:

```
CRLog(@"url:%@",para);
```

and para is

```
http://api.madserving.com/tc.m?aid=2&mod=iPhone%20Simulator&nt=3&os=1&osv=8.3&lng=en_US&jb=&apn=com.XYZ.ABC&av=1.8.0&aas=0&pv=1.1.2&ua=Mozilla/5.0%20(iPhone;%20CPU%20iPhone%20OS%208_3%20like%20Mac%20OS%20X)%20AppleWebKit/600.1.4%20(KHTML,%20like%20Gecko)%20Mobile/12F69
```

My guess is that the %'s in para have tripped `initWithFormat` but I find it odd that this would happen only today when the method has been successfully used for so many months.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Would you mind sharing the error message you get for the crash?

Comment: Here it is Peter: **EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x240000002418)**. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the arg_list twice. NSLogv will change the arg_list. You need to call va_start/va_end twice.

You invoked undefined behaviour, which can strike at any time.

Comment: Thank you @gnasher729! This has solved the problem. Can you please confirm: adding `va_end(arg_list);` and `va_start(arg_list, temp);` after the `NSLogv` has fixed the problem but it won't backfire later will it?